# cannot import name 'spawn' from 'pexpect' on windows

Tags: pexpect, winpexpect

## Trying to ssh tunnel from Windows system through linux jumphost with ip (xx.xx.xx.xx) and connect to target config windows system with ip 127.0.0.1

import sys
import paramiko
import subprocess
import pexpect
from pexpect.popen_spawn import PopenSpawn
import winpexpect
from winpexpect.winspawn import winspawn

child = winpexpect.winspawn('ssh -L 22:xx.xx.xx.xx:4022 Administrator@127.0.0.1 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no')
child.expect('127.0.0.1')
child.sendline('password')

The above program throws below error when run on Windows system.
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\winpexpect.py", line 18, in 
from pexpect import spawn, ExceptionPexpect, EOF, TIMEOUT
ImportError: cannot import name 'spawn' from 'pexpect' (C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pexpect_*init*_.py)

Answer (score 0):

cannot import name 'spawn' from 'pexpect' spawn is not for Windows system. use pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn for windows. check here https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#pexpect-on-windows